# Win Batch, separate single line to multiple

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, linefeed

i have 2 different text files.
Each contains a single line, containing several parameters and/or absolute paths.
Each single parameter and/or path is enclosed in double quotes:

```
-d"some_param" -d"next_param"
-i"c:\some_path" -i"c:\other_path"
```

I want to split that into multiple lines, so one param or path is on a single line. I thought it might help to insert a specific separation token because one of the parameters or paths may contain a space. So i use LL_FF for an easier handling.

```
LL_FF
```

Content file 1:

```
-d"__CHAR_BIT=8"LL_FF -d"__SHRT_BIT=16"LL_FF -d"__INT_BIT=32"LL_FF -d"__LONG_BIT=32"LL_FF -d"CPU_S32K144HFT0VLLT"LL_FF
```

Content file 2:

```
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_proc\C_s32k_conf1\inc"LL_FF -i "C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\includes\prjIncludes\inc"LL_FF -i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\can\canDeviceDriver\inc"LL_FF -i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\hal\clock\inc"LL_FF -i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\hal\intWatchdog\inc"LL_FF -i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\hal\timer\inc"LL_FF -i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\hal\periphery\inc"LL_FF -i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\os\taskGroupManager\inc"LL_FF -i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\os\osInterface\inc"LL_FF
```

I failed to write a batch file generating the following output:

File 1:

```
-d"__CHAR_BIT=8"
-d"__SHRT_BIT=16"
-d"__INT_BIT=32"
-d"__LONG_BIT=32"
-d"CPU_S32K144HFT0VLLT"
```

File 2:

```
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_proc\C_s32k_conf1\inc"
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\includes\prjIncludes\inc"
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\can\canDeviceDriver\inc"
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\hal\clock\inc"
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\hal\intWatchdog\inc"
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\hal\timer\inc"
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\hal\periphery\inc"
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\os\taskGroupManager\inc"
-i"C:\Users\somePath\s_sysprj\os\osInterface\inc"
```

In the param list there is a high possability it will contain special characters like spaces, *, =
And it needs to be a batch script.
Can somebody help me out please?

Thanks and kind regards.

What i tried:
[using replace syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) failed because of special chars \r\n

[regarding this](https://superuser.com/questions/1183502/insert-line-break-special-character-in-string-in-command-line)
i tried this:

```
rem @echo off
SET /p _text=<defines.lnt
echo %_text%
echo
for %%f in ("%_text:LL_FF";"%") do echo aaa %%ff
```

i succeed in reading the file, but i receive no output from the loop.

I also found solutions that might work, but are far to complex to be of any use to me as i would need to much time to understand...
So hence my post here.

[Way to complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953616/batch-command-to-find-a-replace-string-with-line-break)

Comment: There are solutions but "I failed to write a batch file" doesn't really tell us what have you tried.

Comment: Without any code, we have nothing to help you with and your question is off-topic. That said, the following, run on the command line, should put the line from each of those files, `File1.txt` and `File2.txt` into a new file named `Params.txt`: `For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Type File*.txt 2^>Nul') Do @For %B In
(%~A) Do @(Echo %B)>>Params.txt`.

Comment: So.. where is this failing batch file code you speak off?

Comment: @Technically the question doesn't say their batch file code failed, it says that they failed to write a batch file, _this implies that they've tried nothing making their question is off-topic as a direct code request_.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard added it

Comment: @Compo thank you very much, that one works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a batch file example of the code I provided in my comment:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Type File*.txt 2^>Nul') Do For %%B In (%%~A
) Do >>Params.txt Echo %%B
```

This should put the line from each of the files, `File1.txt` and `File2.txt`, into a new file named `Params.txt`, each on a different line as requested.

Comment: Thanks very much, could you be so kind and give me a short description of how this works? Seems like magic...

Comment: @GreenBærg, `For /F` takes each non empty line not beginning with a `;` from all `.txt` files in the working directory whose name begins with the string `File` and `Type`s it as a metavariable `%%A`. That metavarible is then parsed by a `For` loop which naturally splits those lines on certain characters, in this case spaces, and outputs each as a metavariable, `%%B`. That metavariable is `Echo`ed, and in this case, the `Echo` is redirected and appended to a file named `Params.txt` using the `>>` redirection operator.